# Is there some kind of limit of how big the body can be when sending a form with action="mailto:"?

Tags: javascript, post, browser, mailto

Is there some kind of limit of how big the body can be, when sending a form with action="mailto:"? Unable to send body greater than a specific length, in my case 2107 character.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practical terms, no length at all. Using `mailto:` actions requires particular combinations of email clients and web browsers that don't have enough market saturation to make it feasible to use `mailto:` URIs with forms on the WWW.

Use a server side program (e.g. written in Perl/PSGI or PHP/mod_php) instead.

See also: [The Mythical Mailto:](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)